# if clause is not working in a recursive function

Tags: jquery, if-statement

```
function fly() {
    $(".heli").animate({
        top: '-=50px',
        left: '+=25px'
    }, 1000);
    var x = $(".heli").offset().left;
    if (x == 500) {
        alert("match found");
    }
}
$(document).mousedown(function () {
    var Interval = setInterval(fly, 800);
})
```

In the above example, Why the "if clause" of "fly()" doesn't give any result?

Comment: why don't you put a console.log(x) outside of the if loop to verify the actual value?

Comment: and I don't think that this is technically recursion by the way. Your function isn't calling itself, its being called repeatedly by `setInterval`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is probably because you're testing `(x == 500)` *while* the animation is taking place, therefore it won't have incremented the expected amount yet.

Try putting the test in a callback function:

```
function fly() {
    $(".heli").animate({
        top: '-=50px',
        left: '+=25px'
    }, 1000, function(){
        var x = $(".heli").offset().left;
        if (x == 500) {
            alert("match found");
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: It  doesn't alert anything when x=500.

Comment: Also, the problem is that `x` goes up every one second `+=25px`. That means that initially, it must be less than 500 and divisible by 25. +1. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the increment and initial position needing to be able to equal 500 (a way around this may be testing for X >= 500 if you can afford a discrepancy),

You must also make sure your ".heli" elements are positioned "absolute" or "fixed". A "relative" positioned element will not change position no matter how many times you ask it to.